# Windows Apps Universal, XAML or JavaScript

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am embarking on my first windows phone app.  I noticed there are two templates one is in Javascript (Blank App (Universal Apps)) and the other in C# (XAML) again Blank App (Universal Apps).  Which one should I use, I know it depends a lot on the project context, but basically its just a simple phone app, that reads and displays data, mostly crud operations.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd say pick which ever you are more comfortable with.

Comment: But what is the most popular, and what is Microsoft promoting?  I am ok learning a new language.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a lot of resources in the internet regarding this question.

For example:

- http://www.itwriting.com/blog/8350-xaml-and-c-or-html-and-winjs-for-windows-store-universal-and-cross-platform-apps.html
- http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-likes-winjs-for-making-windows-8-apps-but-most-developers-prefer-xaml
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156361/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-xaml-c-or-html5-javascipt-for-metro-apps

If you have a C#/.NET background, choose XAML - if you have a web background, choose WinJS...

I think that XAML is more popular than WinJS (especially for Windows Phone).

Comment: Thanks I went through this, but still I do not get a clear direction, mostly seem to point to XAML/C# combination, but I have doubts about the future of this since everyone is pushing towards the web and open standards

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take to add to the list--http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/01/17/html-javascript-xaml-directx-language-windows-store-app/ . In my partner-facing role at Microsoft I got this question quite a bit, and it really boils down to personal preference and experience unless you run into a place where the languages don't quite have parity at present. Parity was more of an issue in Windows 8, many areas were resolved for Windows 8.1. (Parity is more a matter between Windows/Windows Phone now rather than between the languages.)

Personally, being the author of [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2) (free ebook, Microsoft Press, 2014), I like the JS approach very much because you can leverage standards. On the downside, JS code is the least secure of all the options (see [this blog post of mine](http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/04/04/protecting-your-code/)), which might be a make-or-break consideration.